# Azure CLI to deploy code to function apps where deployment type is ZIP keeps failing

Tags: azure, function, web-applications

Would you mind helping me with the below issue please?

I'm running the below Azure CLI command to deploy code to a function app but the process keeps failing every single time.

`az functionapp deployment source config-zip --name abc --resource-group rg1 --src c:\code\testcode.zip`

The error message I see is

````
Setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to false
Waiting SCM site to be updated with the latest app settings
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
Zip deployment failed. {'id': 'xxxxx-55a9-xxxxx-8651-xxxxxxxe99', 'status': 3, 'status_text': '', 'author_email': 'N/A', 'author': 'N/A', 'deployer': 'Push-Deployer', 'message': 'Created via a push deployment', 'progress': '', 'received_time': '2023-08-07T07:11:13.5364686Z', 'start_time': '2023-08-07T07:11:14.8684051Z', 'end_time': '2023-08-07T07:11:15.8114324Z', 'last_success_end_time': None, 'complete': True, 'active': False, 'is_temp': False, 'is_readonly': True, 'url': 'https://test-eus-func-data-hooks.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest', 'log_url': 'https://test-eus-func-data-hooks.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log', 'site_name': 'test-eus-func-data-hooks.scm.azurewebsites.net'}. Please run the command az webapp log deployment show -n test-eus-func-data-hooks.scm.azurewebsites.net -g test-eus-func-data-hooks.scm.azurewebsites.net*```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding the config item WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE set to 1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-zip-file-requirements